# Caching TGT from a browser

Tags: kerberos

I'm playing around with Kerberos SSO. As experimented so far,

1. When I open a web app that is configured with Kerberos, from the browser, it prompts me for the username and credential, once I enter, I'm logged into the web app.
2. When I do a `kinit` from the terminal and give my credentials, I'm signed into the KDC for the given user. After `kinit`, when I open a web app I'm signed into the web app, without any credentials.

One possible explanation is, when I do a `kinit`, the TGT is stored in the OS which is available for other clients in the host machine so that my browser was able to use that TGT without prompting me for the password.

Now my questions are,

- Will I be able to cache the TGT without using `kinit`?
- If yes, how can I do it using a Java client?
- If the answer to the first question is yes, will I be able to do it from my web app opened in the browser?